# Insert images in a folder into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Im trying to read images from folders into a dataframe , where each row in the dataframe is all the images for a folder :

```
import cv2
import os,glob
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from os import listdir,makedirs
from os.path import isfile,join
import pandas as pd
import PIL
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import imread

pth = 'C:/Users/Documents/myfolder/'

folders =  os.listdir(pth)


videos = pd.DataFrame()
for folder in folders:
   pth_upd = pth + folder + '/'

   allfiles = os.listdir(pth_upd)
   files = []
   columns = ['data']
   index = [folders]
   for file in allfiles:
      files.append(file) if ('.bmp' in file) else None

      samples =  np.empty((0,64,64))
    for file in files:
       img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(pth_upd,file),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

       img = img.reshape(1,64,64)            
       samples = np.append(samples, img, axis=0)

    result = pd.DataFrame([samples], index=[folder], columns=['videos'])
    videos = videos.append(result)
```

after reading all the images in each folder into (samples array ) how can I insert images for each folder in a dataframe row

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
>        in 
>        17         samples = np.append(samples, img, axis=0)
>        18 
>   ---> 19     result = pd.DataFrame([samples], index=[folder], columns=['videos'])
>        20     videos = videos.append(result)

```
 ValueError: Must pass 2-d input
```

:

Comment: I am sure someone can write you code to do what you're asking. I'm not convinced you actually want your images in dataframes, though. You *almost certainly* don't want raw image data in the dataframe (dataframe is the wrong structure for image processing tasks). For example...are you going to do a `groupby` or a `merge` on columns of your image?! What would that even mean? Maybe you wait a *string* representing the file instead and some metadata columns (a dataframe *could* be useful for metadata manipulation)

Comment: I need to use these image for deep learning task like keras cnn

Comment: something wrong with a `dict`? That would be the ideal structure if you're simply looking to map directories to a set of images. I'm not that familiar with `keras` but AFAIK their APIs do not take `pandas` dataframes...

Comment: @MattMessersmith I disagree, I think it's perfectly legitimate to use `pandas` for data engineering and then expose the underlying numpy array with `df.values`. `keras` accepts numpy arrays. (although I'm sure there are arguments for and against using pandas for image datasets)

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible to put strings of the resized images into pandas, but there are much better ways to accomplish CNN training. I adapted your image processing code to show how you could do what you asked:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
import requests
import tempfile
import os
import cv2

# Image processing for the df
def process_imgfile(x):
  img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(
        x.Folder, x.image),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

  img = cv2.resize(img, (64, 64))
  img = str(img)
  return img

# Simulate folders with images in them
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as f:
  f1 = os.path.join(f, "Folder1")
  f2 = os.path.join(f, "Folder2")
  os.mkdir(f1)
  os.mkdir(f2)
  print(r.status_code)
  for x in range(20):
    with open(os.path.join(f1, "f1-{}.jpg".format(x)), "wb") as file1, open(
        os.path.join(f2, "f2-{}.jpg".format(x)), "wb") as file2:

      r = requests.get(
      'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg',
       stream=True)
      for chunk in r.iter_content(16): # File writing...
        file1.write(chunk)
        file2.write(chunk)

  result = [x for x in os.walk(f)]
  folder1 = result[1][2]
  folder2 = result[2][2]

  # Generate dataframe data
  j = {"Folder":[], "image":[]}

  for x in folder1:
    j["Folder"].append(result[1][0])
    j["image"].append(x)
  for x in folder2:
    j["Folder"].append(result[2][0])
    j["image"].append(x)

  # Use the process_imgfile function to append image data
  df = pd.DataFrame(j)
  df["imgdata"] = df.apply(process_imgfile, axis=1)
```

But on a large set of images this is not going to work. Instead, check out [ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-class) which can let you load images at train and test time. It can also help you apply augmentation or synthesize data.

Comment: Thanks @Charles Landau  , I will consider using ImageDataGenerator , but in my code why i'm getting a Nan value in dataframe rows for the folders ?

Comment: You didn't show how you generated that frame so I don't know @N.zay